# Problem with SDL_GetRGBA returning garbage when called on some but not all surfaces

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have a bmp image which I use to create a texture

```
SDL_Surface *temp = SDL_LoadBMP((RES + path + ".bmp").c_str());
surface = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(temp,SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR8888,0);
SDL_FreeSurface(temp);
texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
```

and then save as part of a custom file (everything before and after it are completly fine)

```
struct PixelRGBA{
    unsigned char r,g,b,a;
};  
PixelRGBA *surfaceToPixel(SDL_Surface *surface){
    PixelRGBA *ret = new PixelRGBA[surface->w * surface->h];
    SDL_LockSurface(surface);
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < surface->w * surface->h; i++){
        SDL_GetRGBA(
            ((unsigned int *)surface->pixels)[i],
            surface->format,
            &(ret[i].r),
            &(ret[i].g),
            &(ret[i].b),
            &(ret[i].a));
        std::cout << (unsigned int)ret[i].r << " " << (unsigned int)ret[i].g << " " << (unsigned int)ret[i].b << " " << (unsigned int)ret[i].a << std::endl;
    }
    SDL_UnlockSurface(surface);
    return ret;
}
#define BINO(x) write((char *)&x, sizeof(x))
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const PixelRGBA &obj)
{
    os.BINO(obj.r)
        .BINO(obj.g)
        .BINO(obj.b)
        .BINO(obj.a);
    return os;
}
//How it is saved
PixelRGBA *pixels = surfaceToPixel(obj.surface);
for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < w * h; i++)
    os << pixels[i];
```

In the next run I then load this custom file instead of the bmp

```
#define BINI(x) read((char *)&x, sizeof(x))
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, PixelRGBA &obj)
{
    is.BINI(obj.r)
      .BINI(obj.g)
      .BINI(obj.b)
      .BINI(obj.a);
    return is;
}
SDL_Texture *textureFromSurface(SDL_Surface *surface)
{
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    return texture;
}
SDL_Surface *surfaceFromRGBA(PixelRGBA *data, int w, int h)
{
    SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormatFrom(
        (void *)data,
        w,
        h,
        sizeof(PixelRGBA)*8,
        sizeof(PixelRGBA) * w,
        SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR8888);
    return surface;
}
//How it is loaded
PixelRGBA pixels[w * h];
for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < w * h; i++)
    is >> pixels[i];
obj.surface = surfaceFromRGBA(pixels, w, h);
obj.texture = textureFromSurface(obj.surface);
```

everything is displaying fine and working so far.
But when I then try to save this surface created from memory - with the same method that worked fine for the one created from a bmp - surfaceToRGBA returns complete garbage, not wrongly formated, just garbage (if always similar, first pixel should be 00 00 00 00 but becomes DD FF FF FF).
I checked with both HxD and the std::cout that with the bmp everything is working as intended, it is saved exactly as I want it. And I can load the custom file just fine.
Only when I try to resave it does it break and save random stuff.
But even then the files size doesn't change and the rest of it is still perfectly intact and loaded as intended (checked with HxD and debugger).

The docs say creating a texture from a surface doesn't change it, it isn't freed and it isn't accessed anywhere else. I spent a whole day trying different things like testing if something is wrong with the surfaces pitch/pixelsize in surfaceToPixel, format in surfaceFromRGBA (which is why I know it isn't a mismatched format, I've seen what that would look like and it can't turn 00 00 00 00 into DD FF FF FF f.e.) but the exact same thing happened.

I'm at my wits end. It isn't the end of the world as I don't really need to resave it once it's generated. I can still load the intact version of the custom file just fine. It's just really unsatisfying.
So unless someone figures out what the f is happening here I will move on and continue making the other parts of the programm.

Comment: The obvious problem is that you never check result of `SDL_LockSurface` to figure out whether it succeeded or not.

Comment: @VTT Ok, didn't try that. I'm now checking with `if(SDL_LockSurface(surface)<=0)`, still doesn't work.

Comment: Now this check is always true because `SDL_LockSurface` may return either `-1` or `0`

Comment: I'm stupid. Now >=0 so -1 should trigger it, still not working though.

Comment: If reading example is oversimpified and don't represent actual code (i.e. `pixels` is not placed on stack - if it is, then that is a big deal though) then I suggest using data breakpoint in a debugger to catch a write to said memory.